# When to use Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, time-complexity, big-o

I was attending an Interview today and the interviewer asked what is a dictionary and when should we use it? The 1st part was quite easy but the second part I was unable to answer, I know it is a key value pair but I always used a list of objects to achieve my objective.

I searched a lot read some article  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/500644/Understanding-Generic-Dictionary-in-depth) , [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874390/when-to-use-dictionaries) but I found everyone is answering the How part not the when part, so could you please help me out with some scenarios where I should be using [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2)?

Comment: When you need an *associative* array

Comment: You've really anwsered it yourself - when you need key value pairs. If you don't need that then a list of objects is fine.

Comment: There's whole host of *examples* of where/when to use `Dictionary<T1, T2>` on this famous site here: http://google.com - just type your query and off you go!

Comment: A `Dictionary`, often called a `map` in other languages, provides a data structure whereby finding a value with an associated unique key is performed efficiently.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139052/dictionary-vs-list) would be helpful...

Comment: Two main differences between a list and a dictionary: 1)Each key in a dictionary is unique. 2) Lookup time: To find an item in a list takes O(n) time, in a dictionary O(1).

Comment: @JimG. I don't think that the tags `time-complexity` and `big-o` are relevant to the question. They are relevant to the answers, but the tags in this site are supposed to be associated with the content of the question, not the content of the answers.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I disagree. Often, an OP will ask a question without prior knowledge of what the solution will include. But thank you for your input. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JimG. please take a look at this page at the help center: [​What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). I don't see any association between tags and answers in this page. If you insist on adding the `time-complexity` and `big-o` tags here, would you like to edit also the question in a way that makes these tags relevant with the question itself?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I agree with you, and I'm saying that often the OP doesn't completely understand all of the elements involved in the question they're asking

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I would definitely refrain from adding a tag to a question if the tag merely pertained to one of many answers. What I'm saying is that big-O and time-complexity are necessarily the factors that need to be considered when asking this question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Also consider - https://jakeworth.com/answering-questions-on-stack-overflow/#:~:text=XY%20Problems%2C%20or%20questions%20about,often%2C%20the%20solution%20is%20wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` when you need to store values with some unique keys associated to them, and accessing them by that key is convenient for you.

A lot of people will answer by talking about complexity, speed of access and insertions and things like that. They are not wrong, dictionaries are pretty damn fast, well optimised and offer the performance you need in most cases. Bu in most cases it doesn't really matter, the performance of a chained list of key-value pairs would have also been enough. You will mostly use dictionaries because they are convenient.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually because of the search complexity. Searching in list is O(n), but searching in dictionary is O(1).

However it all depends on the other questions - is the list sorted by the key? If so, then search is O(nlogn), how is the dictionary implemented? In worst case, you can achieve O(n) even with dictionary.

So in general, you use dictionary when you need to search in some collection by some key.

Answer (score 1):

When your Index of an List has to be meaningful and is unique, you could use a Dictionary for better lookup-operations.